# How can I make my (American style) pancakes light and spongy?

Tags: batter, pancakes

I will be participating at a charity event at the end of this month and I am still not sure about my recipe. I am using a mini pancake griddle to cook the pancakes. My pancakes are ok, but I think they can be better.

They weren't very soft--a bit chewy and maybe bread-like. I've had pancakes before that were light and really spongy and that's what I'd like to accomplish.

### My current recipe

- 3 cups of flour
- 3 cups of milk
- 2 tb of oil
- 4 teaspoons of baking powder
- 3 cups of milk  vanilla extract
- 3 eggs
- a pinch of salt
- 2 table spoons of sugar

### Process

I mixed all the wet ingredients together then I mixed the dry ingredients together. I added the wet to the dry and mixed them with an electric mixer for a short time so i don't overmix the batter.

Comment: As recipe requests are not appropriate to this site, I'll just suggest you try buttermilk for a lighter, fluffier result..

Comment: I usually use melted butter in place of the oil. But yeah, recipe requests are off topic here because there are better places to find them. Edit: actually I think this one can be saved with a little re-wording. You have a recipe. You're just looking for a way to make your cakes more spongy and light.

Comment: My yeast pancakes usually come out light and fluffy.

Comment: related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64788/what-do-the-base-ingredients-in-pancakes-do/64796#64796

Comment: Ditto on the butter, and ditto on the buttermilk; my usual recipe uses less baking powder and adds baking soda along with the buttermilk.

I think using an electric mixer with pancakes might be a mistake too - I use a fork or a whisk and mix it just barely, maybe 10-15 seconds tops, even if there are lumps.  I suspect overmixing might be why they were chewy.

Comment: Yep, unless the batter is REAL thin (might be the case though with 6 cups of milk to 3 cups of flour!), an electric mixer tends to mean instant overmixing. Maybe the batter is TOO thin (depends on flour) and cannot hold bubbles from the leavener?

Comment: Google *soda water pancakes* or *seltzer water pancakes*. It's an old diner trick. There are some scratch recipes, you can also use it in the pre-made mixes.

Comment: Yeast and let it rise.  Don't use a mixer.   http://www.breadworld.com/recipes/Beginners-Buttermilk-Pancakes

Comment: Another trick is to separate the eggs, whip the whites to stiff peaks, and fold it back into the batter just before cooking.  I concur with the recommendation to not use a hand mixer, unless you're using a low protein flour like cake flour (which leads to another tip: use a low protein flour).

Answer (score 5):

I can't say for sure what is wrong, but here's a few possibilities:

- Your mix is too runny: if you have a batter that's too thin then it will spread out too far on the pan, if it's too thin you will get a rubbery pancake. It doesn't take much liquid to get too thin, a couple of tablespoons of milk make make the difference between just right and too thick. If you overrun you can always add just a bit of flour
- Your mix is too thick: if your batter is too thick then it will be to stodgy to rise well. You'll get a taller pancake but it won't open up
- Over-mixing: flour has protein in it called gluten, and developed gluten is what makes bread stretchy. Gluten is developed by working it in the presence of moisture, causing gluten strands to uncoil and interlock. Gluten development is good for bread but bad for pancakes risen by baking soda or powder. If you over-mix your pancake batter you will develop the gluten in it, so it's best to do it by hand for as short a time as possible. Don't worry about eliminating all lumps
- pan too hot: if you have the wrong pan temperature it's easy to overcook your pancakes. If it's too hot it will overcook the outside before the inside is done
- pan too cool: If it is too cool then you won't get as much lift, or you lose lift because the batter doesn't set quickly enough to hold in the air, and then you have a close texture. You will also need to cook it longer to get it done, getting a rubber mat instead of a light and fluffy pancake
- Not enough baking powder: Your recipe calls for 4 tsp of baking powder for 3 cups of flour. The non-buttermilk recipe I use would call for 5 tsp. Probably not enough to make the difference between rubbery and fluffy but you never know.

Like others in the comments I also recommend buttermilk for your pancakes as it gives better color, flavor and texture. You can make good pancakes without it for sure, but if I have it available I will always use it.

Answer (score 0):

Theres too much baking powder! Use 1-2 tsp. The more you use, oddly, the less rise you get. Hope that helps!